# What is the frequently used death sound from LEGO Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, lego-star-wars

In the video game *LEGO Star Wars: The Complete Saga*, several characters have this stock death sound, including Luke Skywalker, Captain Panaka, cantina patrons, Kaminoans, and more. Many of the death sounds in the game do come from the films, such as C-3PO's, Jar Jar's and R2-D2's. However, I am not entirely sure if this recurring death sound comes from the films. If it does, what film is it from, and who makes the noise?

[ALL Lego Star Wars: The Complete Saga Death Sounds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHTFj8WpGSg)

The sound can be found at 0:09 in this video.

Comment: All of the sounds appear to be unique (parodies) of sounds from the Star Wars saga. The one you've highlighted is the [Padmé Death Sound](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2AybcQegS4)

Comment: @Valorum Oh, I meant the one immediately after. I'll change it to 0:09.

Comment: The answer remains much the same. It's a generic sound invented by the makers of Lego Star Wars to denote that someone has died

Comment: Is it not the Wilhelm scream? (Or Wilhem, I never remember the spelling!)